# Use *args in function and get this error : " expected string or bytes-like object "

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I tried write a program in this two situation:

> 1.If user don't pass his string as function argument, use input function to get his string.
>
> 2.get function input as a string, if user pass his string as function argument.

After get string from user,calculate the frequency of the words. So, this is my function:

```
def words_frequency(*string_input):
    if not string_input:
        string_input = input("Please write your text: ")
    else:
        string_input = string_input
    input_words = re.sub('[:,:?/;.]', ' ', string_input)
    sorted_words = input_words.lower().split()
    sorted_words.sort()
    print(sorted_words)
    words_dict = {}
    for word in sorted_words:
        words_dict[word] = words_dict.get(word, 0) + 1
    return words_dict

str1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
print(words_frequency(str1))
```

All things in my function is Ok and

> I tested my function with usual method for get argument or get input
>   and both of them run and work in separate situation. **But I can't use
>   them together.**

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you help me? @alain-t

Comment: Your question sounds unclear to me. What do you mean by *I can't use them together*? what is the command that produces the error? What is the full error message?

Comment: `*string_input` will be a tuple not a string. I think you want a default arg instead: `def words_frequency(string_input=None):`

Comment: If you use this function you can see the error. @JacquesGaudin

Comment: Why do you use `*` anyway? Is it necessary?

Comment: yes, thanks for your commnet. I use this two way and both of them help me: `string_input = str(string_input)` or change `*arg` to `agr=None`. If you want write the answer and I choose your answer. @JohnnyMopp

Comment: Also your code isn't a MWE as there is no definition for `re`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I believe what you want to be able to run the words_frequency() function either with a string as input or make it ask for input if the function is ran without input.

You can achieve this by changing the following:

```
def words_frequency(*string_input):
```

to:

```
def words_frequency(string_input=""):
```

I hope this helped, and maybe see [this link](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-function-arguments/) for an explanation of Function Arguments in python :)

And if you Insist on using *string_input, make sure you turn it into String.As a result, you can also use this method:

```
def words_frequency(*string_input):
    if not string_input:
        string_input = input("Please write your text: ")
    else:
        string_input = str(string_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a function parameter with `*` before its name defines an [argument list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). So your function expects not a string, but a list of parameters. You should change `*string_input` (which means several arguments) to `string_input=""` (one optional argument; if it is not defined, use `""`).